# Using PHP Session Variables and an Ajax Loign

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating a login system for  my one  page website using  ajax  and php, I am using this turorial http://forums.devshed.com/php-faqs-stickies-167/program-basic-secure-login-system-using-php-mysql-891201.html. When  a user enters their details and clicks login an ajax post fires  off to the server with the credentials. These credentials are  then validated and if the user was authenticated then the user's details are stored in a session variable and the user is redirected to the main page.

So far the  users details can be validated and the user  is redirected to the  main page. However when the  user  is redirected to the main page these session variables are  no longer set. I am relatively new to php so  am not sure if i am using the session variable correctly.

Here is the HTML of index.php:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <section id="header">

            <div class="logo">

                <h1 id="logoText">Clothing</h1>

            </div>

            <div id="loginWrapper">

                <?php  
                if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                echo  "<script>alert('set')</script>";
                }?>

                <?php if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) { ?>
                <a id="registerButton">Register</a>
                <a id="loginButton">Login</a>
                <?php }
                else  {?>
                    <a id="registerButton"><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></a>
                <?php  } ?>

            </div>

        </section>
        <div class="content" id="panelLogin">

                <div id="loginPageWrapper">

                    <p id="loginHeading">Login</p>

                    <p id="loginError"></p>

                    <form id="loginForm">

                        <p>Username:</p>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="loginUsername"/>
                        <br /><br />

                        <p>Password:</p>
                        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="loginPassword"/>
                        <br /><br /><br />

                        <input type="submit" value="Login" id="loginSubmit" />

                    </form>

                </div>
                <div id="loginErrorWrapper">

                    <div id="loginErrorTextH">Sorry!</div>

                    <div id="loginErrorText">It seems that our login services are temporarily unavailable. Please try again later.</div>

                </div>

            </div>
```

This is the jQuery function that runs when the  login button is clicked:

```
$('#loginSubmit').click(function() {

        event.preventDefault();

        var username = $('#loginUsername').val()
        var password = $('#loginPassword').val()

        if (!username) {
            $('#loginError').text('Please ensure you have entered your username');
            return;
        }
        if (!password) {
            $('#loginError').text('Please ensure you have entered your password');
            return;
        }

        $('.content').css('display', 'none');
        $('#panelLoading').css('display', 'visible');
        $('#panelLoading').css('opacity', '0').fadeTo(1000, 1, 'swing');

        var form = $('#loginForm');

        var loginData = $(form).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'login.php',
            data: loginData
        }).done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
            if (data == 'UserErr') {
                $('#loginError').text('Please ensure you have entered your username');
                return;
            }
            if (data == 'PassErr') {
                $('#loginError').text('Please ensure you have entered your password');
                return;
            }
            if (data == 'LogErr') {
                $('#loginError').text('No user found, please ensure username and password are correct');
                return;
            }
            if (data == 'DBErr') {
                $('.content').css('display', 'none');
                $('#loginPageWrapper').css('display', 'none');
                $('#loginErrorWrapper').css('display', 'visible');
                $('#loginErrorWrapper').css('opacity', '1').fadeTo(1000, 1, 'swing');
                $('#panelLogin').css('display', 'visible');
                $('#panelLogin').css('opacity', '0').fadeTo(1000, 1, 'swing');
                return;
            }
            if (data == 'Success') {
                window.location = 'index.php';
            }
        }).fail(function(data){
            $('.content').css('display', 'none');
            $('#loginPageWrapper').css('display', 'none');
            $('#loginErrorWrapper').css('display', 'visible');
            $('#loginErrorWrapper').css('opacity', '1').fadeTo(1000, 1, 'swing');
            $('#panelLogin').css('display', 'visible');
            $('#panelLogin').css('opacity', '0').fadeTo(1000, 1, 'swing');
            return;
        });
    });
```

These  are the two php scripts used:
common.php:

```
<?php 

    $username = 'root';
    $password = 'Chaz14';
    $host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'clothing';

    $hi = 'Hello';

    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

    try {

        $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex) {

        die("DBErr");
    }

     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

     if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
    { 
        function undo_magic_quotes_gpc(&$array) 
        { 
            foreach($array as &$value) 
            { 
                if(is_array($value)) 
                { 
                    undo_magic_quotes_gpc($value); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $value = stripslashes($value); 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_POST); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_GET); 
        undo_magic_quotes_gpc($_COOKIE); 
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    session_start();
```

login.php:

```
<?php 

    require('common.php');

    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    {

        if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
            die('UserErr');
        }

        if (empty($_POST['password'])) {
            die('PassErr');
        }

        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                name,
                surname,
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                role
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        ";

        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        );

        try { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) { 
            die('DBErr '.$ex->getMessage()); 
        }

        $login_ok = false;

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) { 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 

            if($check_password === $row['password']) { 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 

        if($login_ok) { 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 

            $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
            $_SESSION['surname'] = $row['surname'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
            $_SESSION['role'] = $row['role'];


            die('Success'.$_SESSION['username']); 
        } 
        else { 
            die("LogErr"); 
        } 

    }
```

The details are definitely stored in the  session variable before the redirection of the page, once the redirection takes place they are no longer set

Comment: You need to call `session_start()` at the beginning of any script that wants to use session variables.

Comment: index.php doesn't call `session_start()`.

Comment: Or you can learn some OOP and abstract session access

Comment: @bad_boy Even with OOP, he still has to call the method that calls `session_start()` at the beginning of `index.php`.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah of course, that's obvious. But he would call it only once and then pass `$sessionManager` instance around classes that deal with session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put:

```
<?php session_start ?>
```

before `<body>` in `index.php`.